# Run Estimator in Child run

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Can't create child run of Estimator (Estimator,TensorFlow and PyTorch)

I tried to use submit_child method.

```py
run = experiment.start_logging()

estimator = TensorFlow(source_directory='.',
                      compute_target=cpu_cluster,
                      entry_script='keras.py',
                      pip_packages=["keras"],
                      max_run_duration_seconds= 1200,
                      )

run.submit_child(estimator)
```

```
TrainingException: TrainingException:
    Message: ['_parent_run_id'] parameters cannot be overridden. Allowed parameters are: script_params, inputs and source_directory_data_store.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "['_parent_run_id'] parameters cannot be overridden. Allowed parameters are: script_params, inputs and source_directory_data_store."
    }
}
```

Any workaround or best practice for this scenario ?

Comment: any advice on this ?

Answer (score 0):

In submit_child method estimator object is passed instead of the config object for config parameter. For details on how to configure a run, see the configuration type details.

[ScriptRunConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.scriptrunconfig?view=azure-ml-py)

AutoMLConfig

Pipeline

PublishedPipeline

PipelineEndpoint

Please follow the below link to submit a child using ScriptRunConfig.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py#submit-child-config--tags-none----kwargs-